# Can I use a result from recursion for the same recursion?

Tags: c#, arrays, recursion, binary-search

It's a hard question to paraphrase and a bit of an odd question really. I'm trying to implement a Binary Insertion Sort. I have an array 'a' which contains the values which need to be sorted. Once an individual number is in the right place (found out by the recursion) it returns the array with the sorted number in place and the rest of the array in disarray (haha). This is so that I can focus on the next number in the array to sort. The problem I'm having is that the new improved array isn't being used to call the recursion and each number is being sorted independently in the original completely unsorted array. Is it possible to use the array I've returned in the parameters to call the method with the updated array?

```cs
for (int i = 1; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    a = BinaryInsertSort(a, middle, LeftPointer, RightPointer, i);
}
```

Comment: Arrays in .NET are reference types. So, unless your BinaryInsertSort method explictly clones the array or otherwise creates a new array instance, it will always modify the content of the _same_ array instance that has been passed into it. If that's the case then there is simply no need to return this same array instance after manipulating its content (unless you want to enable fluent coding styles, but which is an entirely different topic unrelated to the logic you want to implement) because the array instance itself has _not_ changed.

Comment: Your example is to small for us to tell where the problem is. It might also be useful if you described what the purpose of this is. There are already perfectly good built in sorting algorithms, no need to build your own. And I would probably not use recursion for something like this. Whenever you use recursion it is important that you have a limited recursion depth. `O(log n)` should be fine, while `O(n)` depth will likely cause StackOverflowException.

Comment: Could you post the rest of your code? It's hard to give a good answer without more context

Comment: I think for now I'll try another way of doing what I am attempting. Thank you everyone for trying to help. I did say it was an odd question. I am now trying this without the For loop external from the recursion.

Comment: if u are doing recursion id write it as a recursive method not a for loop (fair enough to do that after to optimize)...and yes be careful of reference types